# Small Gap Between Background Repeat

Tags: css, animation, background-image

So I've been playing around with CSS animations I can't seem to fix an issues with my background.  I have a small, barely visible gap between my repeating waves.

There isn't a gap on the original image and I'm using an svg image if that makes any difference.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

CSS

```
    .hero {
      background-image: url('waves.svg');
      background-repeat: repeat-x;
      background-position: left bottom;
      height: 500px; 
      position: relative; 
      background-size:50px auto;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="hero">
        <img src="blue_robot.svg" width="350" alt="tall robot" class="clouds cloud1" />
        <img src="blue_robot.svg" width="350" alt="tall robot" class="clouds cloud2" />
        <img src="sailboat.svg" width="350" alt="tall robot" class="sailboat" />
     </div>     
   </div>
```

[image]

Comment: See if this helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11201248/background-image-tiles-have-gap-between-them-when-using-svg-image-how-to-solve

Comment: And there isn't a gap at the edges?  Maybe a really small one?  P.S. I don't notice it without zooming in FYI.

Comment: @Pangloss Awesome, it worked.  Thanks

Comment: @JeffArries it's barely noticeable, but still there.